# Woocommerce keep specific product on hold from orders

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am working on an existing client's site that runs multivendor from yith.
The order management and product updation is done by the admin and not by the vendor.

The scenario is that some products may not be available with a vendor. The customer may add 3 products from a vendor.

So is there a way by which we can keep a specific product on hold in an order (Eg. Order no: #5215) until that product is back on stock after few days and the vendor can ship that specific product later, mean time the vendor can ship other products that are in stock.

Comment: The statuses are applied to the order globally, so the is answer is NO… Now may be you could try to enable for each products the **"back order"** option (that you will get only if the stock management is enabled at the product level).

Comment: Thankyou, but i tried back order settings. It seems to have some problem with back order logic. It simply doesnt allow to add to cart when the stock is set to '0' & 'out-of-stock' with backorder set to 'allowed'. This could have fulfilled my case and the admin would have shipped the product after x number of days. When i put my stock to '0' and select 'in-stock' with back-order 'allowed' add to cart button is visible. So i think the better way is to go the wc traditional way to 'manage stock' and disallow products to be bought  which are out of stock.